# Last item in a list doesn't count

Tags: python

I am writing a program for a school assignment and I have to use data from a .csv file. When I open the file, i read it, and leave it unformatted (all items are strings). I only separate them with commas and create lists within a list. I need to find the last item in a list (there are 3 lists with the same last item). It didn't work in my mail program so I used python shell to confirm that something is wrong.

```
>>> l=[['2', '13:00', '22', '0', 'True', '5\n'], ['-1', '14:00', '22', '0', 'True', '5\n'], ['2', '15:00', '23', '0', 'True', '5\n']]
>>> "5\n" in l
False
>>> "5" in l
False
>>>
```

This is the response it gives me. Why does it not see the last item? Why is there this unnecesary "new line" character?The formatted version shows it as 5 (integer) so it is clearly there.

Comment: That's not an item in the list. That's an item in an item in the list.

Comment: It does not see any item. `'2' in l` will not work either.

Comment: `in` isn't transitive.

Comment: `l` contains two lists, it does not contain `'5\n'`.  `l[0]` and `l[1]` do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test will *not* work for any subitem, for instance:

```
>>> '2' in l
False
```

`x in y` checks for ***direct* membership**. So it should work if you would ask:

```
>>> ['2', '13:00', '22', '0', 'True', '5\n'] in l
True
```

If you want to check *second* level membership, you can use:

```
any("5\n" in li for li in l)
```

which is `True`:

```
>>> any("5\n" in li for li in l)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of all last items you can do a simple list comprehension:

```
last_items = [m[-1] for m in l]
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> last_items = [m[-1] for m in l]

>>> last_items
['5\n', '5\n', '5\n']
```

Comment: Clean, simple solution. And if OP only needs to be aware of their presence, you could do `any(m[-1] == '5\n' for m in l)`, or for the presence in each sublist: `[m[-1] == '5\n' for m in l]`, or for all sublists: `all(m[-1] == '5\n' for m in l)` :-)

Comment: Thank you for adding that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists. This means you have to index the parent list before you can check if an item is inside a child list.

```
'5\n' in l[2]
```

The `l[2]` accesses the 3rd item (because indexes are 0-based in Python) in your list. That 3rd item is itself a list, which you can then to an `in` check against.

If you're hoping for a way to easily do `in` checks on a list of lists, you're out of luck. You'll need to write a loop that loops over each item in your parent list, then does an `in` check on each of the child lists until a match is found.

```
found = False # track whether we found something or not
for child in l:
    if '5\n' in child:
        found = True
        break # we found it, no need to keep looping

if found:
    # if we found something, do something
```

Comment: `l[3]` accesses the *fourth* item in the list, not the third.

Answer (score 0):

```
m=list(zip(*l)[-1])   # last column
if "5\n" in m:
        ...
```